Mongoose aggregate - $filter not removing matching elements
I have the following query that should update the privacyStatus of a user to some value, and also remove all notifications (an array of ObjectIds) which have a type property equal to the value: follow_request.
 User.aggregate([
            {
                $match: { _id: new mongoose.Types.ObjectId(req.user._id) },
            },
            {
                $lookup: {
                    from: "Notification",
                    localField: "notifications",
                    foreignField: "_id",
                    as: "notifications",
                },
            },
            {
                $set: {
                    privacyStatus: value,
                    notifications: {
                        $filter: {
                            input: "$notifications",
                            cond: {
                                $ne: ["$$this.type", "follow_request"],
                            },
                        },
                    },
                },
            },
    
            {
                $merge: {
                    into: "users",
                },
            },
        ]).then((result) => {
            res.send("Done")
        })

The privacyStatus is successfully updated in the database, therefore I know the $match stage is working correctly, however the notifications array doesn't update at all even if there are notifications that match the filter.
My User model:
{
  privacyStatus: {type: Boolean},
  notifications: [type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,ref: "Notification",]
}

Notification Model:
{
   type: {type: String, default: "follow_request"}
}

Why aren't my notifications that have a type of follow_request being removed from the users notification array? Thanks
Sample documents:
user document:
{
   _id: ObjectId('66324110da2f0f7175ca1949'),
   username: "sam",
   notifications: [
      ObjectId('663c1c0bd0sa68fae7cf6ad2')
   ]
}

Notification document:
{
   _id: ObjectId('663c1c0bd0sa68fae7cf6ad2'),
   type: "follow_request"
}


$filter is expected to keep the items that match with the filter, not removing them.

Share some sample documents as it's likely you have a typo somewhere or the data fields don't match in the merge stage because based on your aggregation your code should keep notifications in the array if type is not equal to follow_request i.e. remove notifications where type is equal to follow_request. See here. For example if User.notifications is defined as an array of Objectids in your schema you can't insert full Notification documents into them during the merge.

You could wrap the $filter in a $map to only return the _ids like this

Yup, you are changing the structure/type of notifications from an array of ObjectIds to an array of objects. So the lookup will work the first time for a given userId but after that would not match anything in the foreign collection, since the User's notifications _id is now in notifications._id and not just notifications.

@aneroid Ok so because I’m doing a lookup, when using filter, I am returning an array of objects instead of just an id? How could I return only the ids when filtering ?

@jQueeny In the example you provided with the map, the merge stage is missing. Is it still required to update a document in your example ?

@ray yes it should remove all the notifications with a type of follow_request

Yes you would still need the merge stage. Have you tried it?  See here for an example with the $merge stage.

@jQueeny That’s fantastic thank you. Could you please explain why map is necessary for this use case? I believe it takes an array as an input and then applies an expression to each array element and returns a new array. Is this correct, and why is it used for  this particular use case ?

That's correct. The $filter operator returns the array of filtered objects which is then the input to the $map to step through each array element and in this case only return the _id. That leaves you with an array of just ObjectIds - which I gather is what you need.

@jQueeny I have just implemented the code you provided into my project, and it seems to delete all notifications even if the type is not equal to follow_request.

@jQueeny Also please check my updated post to see the sample documents

Is your collection called Notification or notifications? My guess is it's the latter. In which case you need to modify the $lookup stage. i.e from: "notifications" Also, the User model and  Notification model you provided are very, very minimal. In future you would need to include how they are constructed, not just an extract.

@jQueeny I fixed it using your advice. Thank you!

@jQueeny Is it possible for me to mark your comment is a correct answer? I have upvoted it however i cant seem to mark it as correct

To get your aggregate to merge the results back intot he users collection you need to do two things:

Change the collection used in the $lookup from Notification to notifications.
Recognise that your User.notifications field is an array of ObjectIds. When your $filter returns it's results, you won't be able $merge them back into your User.notifications array because they will be full Notification documents. That can be fixed with a $map stage to step over each filtered Notification document and only return their _id. Then that will match your schema.

The finished aggregation might look like this:
User.aggregate([
  {
    $match: {
       _id: new mongoose.Types.ObjectId(req.user._id)
    }
  },
  {
    $lookup: {
      from: "notifications", //< change to this
      localField: "notifications",
      foreignField: "_id",
      as: "notifications"
    }
  },
  {
    $set: {
      privacyStatus: value,
      notifications: {
        $map: {
          input: {
            $filter: {
              input: "$notifications",
              cond: {
                $ne: [
                  "$$this.type",
                  "follow_request"
                ]
              }
            }
          },
          as: "n",
          in: "$$n._id"
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $merge: {
      into: "users"
    }
  }
]).then((result) => {
   res.send("Done")
})

See HERE for a working example.
